# Swap elements inside Realm Object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Here's my code in which I want to swap child objects (origin and destination) in Realm:

```
class TrainSearchOptions: Object {
    dynamic var origin: Station?
    dynamic var destination: Station?
    dynamic var date: Date?

    func swapPlaces() {
        guard origin != nil && destination != nil else {
            fatalError()
        }

        swap(&origin!, &destination!)
    }
}
```

But this crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this inside Realm write transaction.

```
do {
       try realm.write {
           swap(&origin!, &destination!)
       }
   } catch let error as NSError {
       print(error)
   }
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily, you can update a realm object outside of a write transaction. The transaction is only necessary when you add / delete / update the object.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was completely wrong as my comment was only true when handling unmanaged objects.